# MS Access IIF Query if Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif, iif-function

I'm trying to create an access query based on the date field, the query i Have which runs but doesn't populate the correct information is as follows

```
IIf([Last Pyt Date]>DateAdd("d",-60,Date()),'Arrangement in place'))
```

the "Last Pyt Date" needs to be within the last 60 days to populate "Arrangement in place" otherwise I will specify different information to populate if the day of Last Pyt is older than 60 days.

Comment: What does "doesn't populate the correct information" mean?

Comment: If that worked for you can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to reverse your logic to match your description

```
IIf( Date() < DateAdd("d", 60, [Last Pyt Date]), 'Arrangement in place')
```

Comment: that's perfect. Thanks a mil!

Comment: Perfect? It will kill any use of the index on `[Last Pyt Date]`.